# ncurses and stdin blocking

Tags: select, stdin, blocking, ncurses, curses

I have *stdin* in a `select()` set and I want to take a string from *stdin* whenever the user types it and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But select is triggering *stdin* as ready to read before <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit, and, in rare cases, before anything is typed at all. This hangs my program on `getstr()` until I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I tried setting `nocbreak()` and it's perfect really except that nothing gets echoed to the screen so I can't see what I'm typing. And setting `echo()` doesn't change that.

I also tried using `timeout(0)`, but the results of that was even crazier and didn't work.

Comment: Well basically I'm wondering if I HAVE to use threads now because of ncurses, because I can do that, but it's not as elegant as just using select.

The only other option I can think of, is to read every char and try to do some radical processing of them. This seems like it could be even messier.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is tho check if a character is available with the getch() function. If you use it in no-delay mode the method will not block. Then you need to eat up the characters until you encounter a '\n', appending each char to the resulting string as you go.

Alternatively - and the method I use - is to use the GNU readline library. It has support for [non-blocking behavior](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html), but documentation about that section is not so excellent.

Included here is a small example that you can use. It has a select loop, and uses the GNU readline library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int quit = false;

void rl_cb(char* line)
{
    if (NULL==line) {
        quit = true;
        return;
    }

    if(strlen(line) > 0) add_history(line);

    printf("You typed:\n%s\n", line);
    free(line);
}

int main()
{
    struct timeval to;
    const char *prompt = "# ";

    rl_callback_handler_install(prompt, (rl_vcpfunc_t*) &rl_cb);

    to.tv_sec = 0;
    to.tv_usec = 10000;

    while(1){
        if (quit) break;
        select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &to);
        rl_callback_read_char();
    };
    rl_callback_handler_remove();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall rl.c -lreadline
```

Comment: Thanks.

I tried using the readline solution, it looks nice, but it still doesn't echo properly when using curses at the same time. They probably aren't mean to be used together.

I decided to just use getch() and maintain an internal buffer of the line. It's surprisingly easy.