# How to select on socket using libreadline?

Tags: c, sockets, select, readline

I'm writing a C program that presents a 'pseudo-terminal' to the user where they can enter special commands, and also needs to listen for data from a UDP socket.

Currently I'm using the select() call to select on STDIN and the socket handle. When it returns, I use the FD_ISSET() macro to determine whether the program should respond to a user-command or socket data.

```
while (1) {
    fd_set fs;
    FD_ZERO(&fs);
    FD_SET(0, &fs);  // stdin.
    FD_SET(socket, &fs);

    int ret = select(s + 1, &fs, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (FD_ISSET(0, &fs)) { /* handle terminal command from stdin. */ }

    if (FD_ISSET(socket, &fs)) { /* handle socket data. */ }
}
```

I want to use the GNU readline library to implement the terminal, so that I can take advantage of its history and tab-completion features. It seems that the readline() function uses it's own method to read from stdin however, and I can't see a way of also selecting on the UDP socket.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could call `readline` whenever select returns and `stdin` is ready to be read, but then you commit to reading an entire line of input whenever the user presses a key. If you want to handle input on both file descriptors, consider using separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

Readline provides a way to do this:
  http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html

Basically your code is fine. You need to call an initialization function, and then where you have `/* handle terminal command from stdin. */`, you call `rl_callback_read_char()`.

You can see a simple example in this answer:
  [ncurses and stdin blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706678/ncurses-and-stdin-blocking)